# Experiencing "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Identity.Application" while trying to run via IIS Express

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Created User extending from IdentityUser under Areas -> Identity -> Data. Named the User model MedicalManagerUser which consists additional properties Country, City, First &  Last names. Screen shot added to provide the project setup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKWwl.jpg)

Note, the User to be used in the application defined in Project (e.g. MedicalManager) -> Models.

**Can someone please help. I am stuck for a  while..**

```
Here is the link to  the project, feel free to download and help debug. 

**https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development.git**

You help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks
```

Comment: Your link is invalid,you can share your context and startup with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-model),you can see,if you want to custom a `User`.

**Update**:

You need to perform the following steps.

**In your context:**

You need change your code to

```
public class MedicalManagerDBContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public MedicalManagerDBContext(DbContextOptions<MedicalManagerDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Medication> Medications { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

**In your startup:**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        services.AddDbContext<MedicalManagerDBContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MedicalManagerDBContextConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MedicalManagerDBContext>();

    }
```

**And in your `_LoginPartial`,`Login`,`Logout`,`Register` you need to replace MedicalManagerUser with User:**

```
SignInManager<User> SignInManager
UserManager<User> UserManager
```

**Drop database, delete previous migration files， then remigration and update database.**

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Same issue. Here is the screen shot. I wonder if you could checkout the code locally from   the  git location:

Comment: Yinqiu, https://github.com/biteus/ The repository name: mmm_development . The  Repo made public for you to access.

Comment: Hi @Bite-us,I have updated my answer.

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?Merry Christmas:)

Comment: Great!!!!!!... Almost there. Updating those cshtml with the User was a great catch. Also it seems like in the DbContext's MonModelCreating I don't need to redefine the relationship as in the Model itself one-many defined having public virtual  ICollection<Medication> Medications { get; set; } called out in User model. However, while running it is complain. I already made a branch Stackoverflow_Yinqiu @ https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development.git If you would kindly review what missed and push your change that works. I tried to run via IIS Express and see the following ..

Comment: This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44332/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: Hi@Bite-us,in your _LoginPartial,Login,Logout,Register you need to replace MedicalManagerUser with User.You need to find them and update.

Comment: I  did already. Even though I  managed  to get  to render the page & conduct the Registration by form  filling but application does not navigate to the Home page as logged in. Neither does it give any error message. Video clip attached and also pushed the code in https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development/tree/Yinqiu I wonder if you would be kind enought to have a quick look at your connvinience.  You can push back the updated code to your branch with commit comments. In this repo : https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development.git I got a branch of Yinqiu